# Use simpleform to add date time field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, field, simple-form

I want to way to add date and time as a simpleform field. Based on the simpleform documentation I was trying

```
  <%= f.datetime select :time, :as => :datetime %>
```

but I am receiving an "Argument Error in Houses#new".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work" means?  Raises an error? Or doesn't render the expected input?

I'd guess this should look more like:

```
f.input :time, :as => :datetime
```

Comment: `<%= f.input :time, :as => :datetime %>`